# PHP Design Pattern, separation of concerns: should the Controller make a new HTTP request to the API?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, php, api, controller

I'm having a huge doubt on how to connect the front-end of my application to its back-end.

So my application has a single entry point where all requests go.
The request is dispatched to a controller, which, in turn, needs to call the logic (the model), which elaborates the data, communicates with the database and returns some data for the view.

Now here I could just (as I used to do years ago) include everything in PHP, and call the model directly from the controller and have probably an easier life lol
..but I feel like it could be done in a better way, which would also permit to have multiple instances of the clients and one server and to have a nice separation of concerns in the whole architecture.

My idea is to build an API for the models and making the Controllers call it with a new HTTP request.

So, my question is (**TLDR**): **should the Controller make a new HTTP request to the API?**
since all the code is running on the same machine, is it bad to make new HTTP requests (to localhost) when I could just include the models and directly call them from the controllers?
Because on each page load there could be multiple API calls, and so HTTP requests (up to 4/5).

Here below is a schematization of how it would be.
If you are about to downvote my post can you please at least leave a comment? Thanks.

[image: scheme of the application]

Here's a synthesized version of the code:

bootstrap.php:

```
/* above there's configuration loading */
$container = new Container();
$container->createClass("PDO");
$container->createClass("Requests");
$page = $container->createClass("Page");

$pageInfo = $page->loadPage();

if($pageInfo['has_a_controller']){
    $container->createClass($pageInfo['page_controller_name']);
    // calls the page controller which handles the request
    $container->callClassMethod($pageInfo['page_controller_name'], "initializeController");
}

// this is the default view:
require(TEMPLATE_DIR . "template.php");
```

exampleController.php:

```
class exampleController {
    private $news;
    private $container;
    private $requests;
    private $page;

    public function __construct(Container $container, Page $page, Requests $requests){
        // these dependencies are solved by the container
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->requests = $requests;
    }

    public function initializeController() {
        // loading the model class, this is the direct call, without the API
        $this->news = $this->container->createClass("News");

        // in terms of code my question would be making a HTTP request here (removing `private $news` and adapting the below so)

        // configuring the class (simplified)
        $this->news->setCurrentPage($this->requests->get("news_page"));
        $this->news->setNewsPerPage($this->requests->get("news_show"));


        $commentController = $this->container->createClass("CommentController");
        $commentController->initializeController();
    }

    // as now, these functions are directly called by the view in this way:
    // $container->callClassMethod(*controller name*, *function name*, * params *);

    public function getNews(){
        return $this->news->getNews();
    }
    public function getPageCount(){
        return $this->news->getPageCount();
    }
    public function getNewsSomethingFooBar(){
        return $this->news->getNewsSomethingFooBar();
    }
}
```

newsmodel.php

```
class News {
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    public function getNews() {
        try {
            $query = "SELECT id, title, date, content FROM news ORDER BY date DESC";
            $stmt = $this->pdo->query($query);
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            // error handling
        }
    }
    public function getPageCount() {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM news");
            $news_count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
            if($this->getNewsPerPage() == 0) {

                return 0;
            }
            return ceil($news_count / $this->getNewsPerPage());
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            // error handling
        }
    }
    // here are some other example functions
    public function addNews($title, $content, $date) {
        // admin function
    }
    public function editNews($old_id, $id, $date, $title, $content) {
        // admin function
    }
    public function deleteNews($id) {
        // admin function
    }
}
```

PS. I've moved this question here because it was considered off-topic on codereview. Also how would you call this architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really matter.

As long as it's indeed a Controller - a little servant between an HTTP request and a Model - it doesn't really matter how this request to the Model is made. Once you'd decide to move the Model to the separate server, you can simply change the calling method as well. Or you could create a simple adapter that translates the calls to the model to API calls.

However, for the moment I wouldn't bother with making an API. Instead I would focus on the database infrastructure. It's a database that create all the payload. Hence consider moving the database to the separate server as the first step.

The next step would be using the master/slave replication and allow the Model to choose the server it interacts with. All the writes, reads that rely on the writes, transactions - must go on the master. All other reads should go the the slaves. On the database level there is already a well established distributed infrastructure, so you won't have to reinvent the wheel. And it is well scaled on the backend level as well.

Answer (score 0):

### What is the API for?

Your diagram is oddly "hourglass shaped": the main application despatches to different controllers, but these then all apparently call the same API. Implicitly, that API will then need to re-despatch those calls to various separate implementations. It's not clear what this separation is trying to achieve.

One possibility is that you're building a kind of "headless backend" - something which has a bunch of logic about *what* to show, but leaves *how* to show it to a separate "front-end" application. This can be used to write the two parts in different technologies: a front-end in a Single-Page Architecture JS framework and a back-end in PHP; or a front-end in a bespoke e-commerce application, and a CMS component using Drupal or Wordpress. It can also be used to re-use the same back-end with multiple front-ends, e.g. making the API available directly to third-parties while using it to build your own website.

Another possibility is that you're trying to separate your persistence and business logic into microservices. The idea in that case is that each logical part of your application gets its own service - a "news" microservice and a "products" microservice etc. What you've labelled "controllers" then become something like an "API gateway" layer: working out which microservices to call, and passing data between them.

### Is Model View Controller the right mental model?

The MVC pattern was originally designed for desktop applications. It then became a popular way to try to describe web application frameworks, but it's a bit of an awkward fit. While "Controller" and "View" have fairly obvious meanings, "Model" tends to end up covering "everything else", which isn't particularly helpful.

The boxes you label "Model" actually cover a wide variety of components:

- Domain entities: value objects representing news items, products, whatever you're dealing with.
- Business logic: ideally, self-contained functions that take some entities and configuration, and spit out some new entities or results.
- Persistence: service classes providing things like database access.
- Integrations: service classes which call external APIs, run other software on the server, etc.

This becomes even more of a muddle when you've got multiple layers, each able to operate independently. In both the above cases, the "back-end application" or "microservices" will be complete applications, which might themselves have equivalents of controllers and views. And in both cases, the "front-end application" or "API gateway" will have its own value objects to represent the data coming back and pass it to the final view.

Comment: Yeah, I'm writing a "headless back-end", but the front-end it's also written in PHP, there is zero javascript. 
The API I'm describing would basically load a requested class (and this would be its despatching), call one of its methods and return its response. I don't know if I would call those classes/models or microservices, they're just classes that connect to a database (and get, update or delete the data from it).